# Dispatch function in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm studying react and I have an example like this

```
//index.js
const store = createStore(reducer)
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AddTodo />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

//Apptodo.js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
    .......
```

Why didn't it get `this.pros.store` but simply call the dispatch() function ?

EDIT: How does it extract the `dispatch` from `this.pros`. Isn't the object `this.pros.store` ? and in this case why don't we just extract `store` ?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you're conflating the concepts of both React and Redux. Props are what you get with React components. The Redux store is not related in any way. react-redux is connecting them, making it easier for you to dispatch actions using Redux's store method, dispatch(). react-redux can also make the store's state available as props, by passing in a function as the first argument to connect() Check out the react-redux docs for more information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `addTodo` component has access to the store's state and methods(e.g, dispatch, getState, etc). So, when you hooked up your React view with the Redux store via the `connect` method, you had access to store's state and methods.

`({ dispatch })` is simply using JS [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract `dispatch` from `this.props` object.

Comment: thank you, I will read about this, but why do we want to extract dispatch ? isn't it enough to extract store ?

Comment: You can't extract the store. react-redux 's [Provider](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) component makes the entire redux store available to the components in the hierarchy below via the [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method. So, the component has the `store's` methods and state merged into its props.  To access `dispatch` , it can access it through `this.props.dispatch`.

Answer (score 34):

[react-redux is the library](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples) that is passing these methods to your component as props.

[dispatch() is the method used to dispatch actions](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) and trigger state changes to the store. react-redux is simply trying to give you convenient access to it.

Note, however, that dispatch is not available on props if you do pass in actions to your connect function. In other words, in the code below, since I'm passing `someAction` to connect, `dispatch()` is no longer available on props.

The benefit to this approach, however, is that you now have the "connected" action available on your props that will **automatically be dispatched** for you when you invoke it.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { someAction } from '../myActions';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // someAction is automatically dispatched for you
  // there is no need to call dispatch(props.someAction());
  props.someAction();
};

export default connect(null, { someAction })(MyComponent);
```

Or if we were to use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as shown in the example you give...

```
const MyComponent = ({ someAction }) => {
  someAction();
};
```

It's important to note, however, that you must invoke the connected action available on props. If you tried to invoke someAction(), you'd be invoking the raw, imported action — not the connected action available on props. The example given below will **NOT update the store**.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // we never destructured someAction off of props
  // and we're not invoking props.someAction
  // that means we're invoking the raw action that was originally imported
  // this raw action is not connected, and won't be automatically dispatched
  someAction();
};
```

This is a common bug that people run into all the time while using react-redux. [Following eslint's no-shadow rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682705/avoid-no-shadow-eslint-error-with-mapdispatchtoprops/42337137#42337137) can help you avoid this pitfall.

Comment: Missing a '}' in `const MyComponent = ({ someAction ) => {`?